# scala: yield pairwise combinations of two loops

Tags: scala

I would like to create a collection with tuples containing all pairwise combinations of two lists. Something like:

```
for ( x <- xs )
  for ( y <- ys ) 
    yield (x,y)
```

In Python this would work, in Scala apparently `for` yields only for the last loop (so this evaluates to `Unit`)

What is the cleanest way to implement it in Scala?

Comment: Nicolas's answer is the correct one, but note that `for` evaluates to Unit only when there is no yield. Check `for(x <- xs) yield for (y <- ys) yield (x,y)`, it returns something interesting, but not exactly what you wants.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
scala> val xs = List (1,2,3)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val ys = List (4,5,6)
ys: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> for (x <- xs; y <- ys) yield (x,y)
res3: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6))
```

Answer (score 11):

A little bit more explicit according to Nicolas:
In Scala you can use multiple generators in a single for-comprehension.

```
val xs = List(1,2,3)
val ys = List(4,5)

for {
  x <- xs
  y <- ys
} yield (x,y)

res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5))
```

You can even evaluate in the comprehension.

```
for {
  x <- xs
  y <- ys
  if (x + y == 6)
} yield (x,y)

res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,5), (2,4))
```

Or make an assignment.

```
for {
  x <- xs
  y <- ys
  val z = x + y
} yield (x,y,z)

res2: List[(Int,Int,Int)] = List((1,4,5), (1,5,6), (2,4,6), (2,5,7), (3,4,7), (3,5,8))
```

Comment: And what if I would like to loop `xs` and `ys` _and_ increment come counter `cnt` at every iteration? Like: `for(x<-xs; y<-ys; cnt++) yield(x,y,cnt)` ?

Comment: val concatenator = for { x <- xs, y <- ys } yield (x, y); concatenator.zipWithIndex. You might flatten this result but it is counted.

Comment: for- comprehensions are cool, i am discovering them for myself as well, and really like them especially with scalaz's validations